# c# login page SQL error

Tags: c#, authentication

c# code:

```
  namespace WpfApplication22
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select * from Users where username='"textBox1.Text +"' and pasword= '"textBox2.Text +"' ", conn);
                conn.Open();

    }
            }
        }
```

What is wrong with this, I am getting 11 errors...can anyone can help me?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGCbZ.jpg] list of errors

Comment: You are missing the `+` character between some of your strings. `"Blah" + textBox1.Text + "blah" + textBox2.Text + "blah"`.

Comment: Your current SQL statement is also prone to SQL injection, please consider using parametrisation.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Consider using Ctrl+K,D to format your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (
"Select * from Users where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password= '" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
```

You want to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by using something like the following

```
SqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE TableID = @Parameter";
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter", parameterValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've lost '+' signs before of textBoxes Texts.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select * from Users where username='" + textBox1.Text +"' and pasword= '" + textBox2.Text + "' ", conn);
```

But you'd better use command parameters in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password= '" + textBox2.Text + "' ", conn);`

You were missing `+` signs before reading the textbox text and you misspelled `password` in your query.

But you should really scrap this and use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) instead.  You're leaving yourself vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that the correct answer has already been given but you are also making a huge mistake by injecting the contents of a text box directly into your SQL command. This leaves it open to SQL Injection attacks which can literally destroy your entire DB.

Always, always use parameters to avoid this problem.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select * from Users where username=@username and pasword=@password ", conn);
cmd .Parameters.AddWithValue("username", textBox1.Text);
cmd .Parameters.AddWithValue("password", textBox2.Text);
                conn.Open();
```

read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection